# Duplex Printing not working in ubuntu 21.10

Tags: hp, duplex-printing

**duplex** printing does **not work** in ubuntu 21.10 within applications like LibreOffice, Firefox or PDF-document viewer. I can select options like double side long edge/short edge, but it always prints single side. It just works with the HPLIP-Toolbox. Obviously the HP Toolbox is using different printer drivers.
Somebody an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably worth editing your question to include details of your printer. Thanks.

Comment: Unable to duplicate with the given information. I just printed a 10-page double-sided PDF from Evince (PDF Viewer) on 21.10 as usual. I suggest noting the time, running a test print, then checking your logs (`/var/log/syslog` and `journalctl`) for messages around the noted time.

Comment: My printer is HP Photosmart 5520

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 21.10 64-bit; GNOM-Version 40.4.0; Windows Manager: Wayland

Comment: Nov 07 10:01:21 linux-ws-01 systemd[1714]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Nov 07 10:01:22 linux-ws-01 gnome-shell[7660]: (WW) Option "-listen" for file descriptors is deprecated
Nov 07 10:01:22 linux-ws-01 gnome-shell[7660]: Please use "-listenfd" instead.
PrintStart: 10:01:00 Nov 07 10:01:22 linux-ws-01 gnome-shell[7660]: (WW) Option "-listen" for file descriptors is deprecated
Nov 07 10:01:22 linux-ws-01 gnome-shell[7660]: Please use "-listenfd" instead.
Nov 07 10:01:23 linux-ws-01 gnome-shell[7660]: glamor: No eglstream capable devices

Comment: This is just part of related messages during printing. Dont know how to show longer messages because of limitation of comments.

Answer (score 0):

During upgrade from ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10 the HPLIP was not upgraded to hplip-3.21.10. After upgrading HPLIP to 3.21.10 everything works fine!